# How To Return Incorrectly Predicted Images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a list containing the first 10 image IDs that were incorrectly predicted.

```py
import os
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import 
DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
batch_size=128


def predict_image(img, model):
    # Convert to a batch of 1
    xb = to_device(img.unsqueeze(0), device)
    # Get predictions from model
    yb = model(xb)
    # Pick index with highest probability
    _, preds  = torch.max(yb, dim=1)
    # Retrieve the class label
    return dataset.classes[preds[0].item()]

def invalid_predictions(n=10):
    invalid_ids = []
    while invalid_ids
    return invalid_ids
    # This method should return a list of first 
    # 10 image ids that the model could not 
    # predict correctly.
    # For example [40, 35, 20, ...]
```

Comment: you need to have the true labels of the images, in addition to the predicted labels, in order to tell if an image was correctly or incorrectly predicted.

Answer (score 1):

```
def invalid_predictions(n=10, images, labels):
    invalid_ids = []
    image_count = 0
    invalid_count = 0
    while invalid_count < n:
        prediction = predict_image(images[image_count], model)
        if prediction != labels[image_count ]:
            invalid_ids.append(image_count )
            invalid_count +=1
        image_count += 1
    return invalid_ids
```